# Multiple Show/Hide with changing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I have a multiple show/hide divs with changing texts *from **Expand** to **Reduce***. If there is more than one dropdown, text doesn't changing. There is my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/fL1ywcr7/), you can test it, by delete one section. Any solutions for that? :)

This is my JQuery

```
$(".section .section-title").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".section").find('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(100);
  $(this).find('.expand').toggleClass('expanded');

  if ($.trim($(".expand").text()) === 'Expand') {
    $(".expand").text('Reduce');
} else {
    $(".expand").text('Expand');        
}

});
```

Comment: which dropdown? do you mena extra div?

Comment: Your if condition is not working, use
if($.trim($(this).find('.expand').text()) === 'Expand'){
    $(this).find(".expand").text('Reduce');
} else {
    $(this).find(".expand").text('Expand');        
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must find text with class `.expand` in `this`,which represents the `section` clicked.

Use this:

```
$(".section .section-title").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".section").find('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).find('.expand').toggleClass('expanded');

    if ($.trim($(this).find(".expand").text()) === 'Expand') {
        $(this).find(".expand").text('Reduce');
    } else {
        $(this).find(".expand").text('Expand');        
    }
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL1ywcr7/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You should find `.expand` in `this` (or `closest(".section")`) :

```
$(".section .section-title").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".section").find('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(100).end()
  .find('.expand').toggleClass('expanded').text(function(){
    return $(this).is('.expanded') ? 'Reduce' : 'Expand';
  });
});
```

```js
$(".section .section-title").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".section")
    .find('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(100).end()
    .find('.expand').toggleClass('expanded').text(function(){
      return $(this).is('.expanded') ? 'Reduce' : 'Expand';
    });
});
```

```css
.section .section-title{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #f3f5f9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}

.section .title{
    margin: 9px 0 0 45px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.section .title:before{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 20px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "• ";
    color: #a8a8a8;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 48px;
}

.section .dropdown-content{
    display: none;
}

.section .expand{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.section .expanded{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section personal-info">
  <div class="section-title">
    <div class="title">Personal info</div>
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas elementum lacus vel posuere placerat. Morbi ligula turpis, accumsan vitae lectus quis, aliquet sagittis est. Ut congue neque enim, et malesuada nisi sollicitudin nec. Morbi eget mauris rutrum, vestibulum orci sit amet, sollicitudin nisi. 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section residence-address">
  <div class="section-title">
    <div class="title">Other info</div>
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    Etiam vestibulum elementum orci sit amet auctor. Vestibulum vel nisl nec velit fermentum convallis vel ut enim. Aliquam imperdiet justo urna, ut efficitur purus ornare ut. Praesent imperdiet venenatis mauris non luctus. Nullam in arcu nec arcu auctor aliquam sit amet at nisl. Donec pharetra, leo ut imperdiet convallis, risu
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> If there is more than one dropdown, text doesn't changing

This is because `$(".expand").text()` returns text of all elements with class `expand`.
In your example returns: *"ExpandExpand"* and therefore the condition `=== 'Expand'` is not meet.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to check the text of all elements matching `.expand`. So if you have more than one dropdown this doesn't work.

Try this one:

```
$(".section .section-title").click(function(){
$(this).closest(".section").find('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(100);
$(this).find('.expand').toggleClass('expanded');

if ($.trim($(this).find('.expand').text()) === 'Expand') {
  $(this).find('.expand').text('Reduce');
} else {
  $(this).find('.expand').text('Expand');        
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change this it will work.

```
$(this).find($(".expand")).text()
```

instead of

```
$.trim($(".expand").text())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
 $(".section .section-title").click(function(){
 $(this).closest(".section").find('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(100);
 $(this).find('.expand').toggleClass('expanded');

 if ($.trim($(this).find(".expand").text()) === 'Expand') {
   $(this).find(".expand").text("Reduce");
 } else {
    $(this).find(".expand").text("Expand");        
 }
});
```